# Vectorizing non-trivial for loop in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am trying to make this code run faster by vectorizing it as I believe for loops in python are slow. I don't entirely understand vectorizing so the slicing inside the for loop is causing me trouble.

Note: This is for an assignment where any non numpy libraries aren't allowed.

```
self.gx = numpy.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
self.gy = numpy.array([[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])

def create_vector(self, image):
    """Creates a gradient vector for each pixel in the image

    Returns: vec_data: [mag, angle, avg_value]"""
    vec_data = numpy.zeros((image.shape[0], image.shape[1], 3), dtype='float')

    for y in xrange(1, image.shape[0]-1):
        for x in xrange(1, image.shape[1]-1):

           #Get 3x3 matrix around the pixel
           subimage = image[y-1:y+2,x-1:x+2]

           #Apply sobel operator
           dx = (self.gx*subimage).sum()
           dy = (self.gy*subimage).sum()

           vec_data[y,x,0] = abs(dx) + abs(dy)
           vec_data[y,x,1] = abs(math.atan2(dx,dy))
           vec_data[y,x,2] = subimage.sum()/9 #Average of 3x3 pixels around x, y

    return vec_data
```

Comment: Does `scipy` count as non-`numpy`?

Comment: There might be some ideas here [Faster way to calculate sum of squared difference between an image (M, N) and a template (3, 3) for template matching?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17881489/faster-way-to-calculate-sum-of-squared-difference-between-an-image-m-n-and-a)

Comment: Yeah I'm not allowed scipy cause then i could just use the sobel function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The straightforward vectorization of your code is done with a windowed view:

```
import numpy as np

image = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
gx = np.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
gy = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])
gm = np.ones((3, 3))/9
rows, cols = image.shape
k_rows, k_cols = gx.shape

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided
image_view = as_strided(image, shape=(rows - k_rows + 1, cols - k_cols + 1,
                                      k_rows, k_cols),
                        strides=image.strides*2)
dx = np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij',image_view, gx)
dy = np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij',image_view, gy)
dm = np.einsum('ijkl,kl->ij',image_view, gm)

>>> dx
array([[-8, -8, -8],
       [-8, -8, -8],
       [-8, -8, -8]])
>>> dy
array([[-40, -40, -40],
       [-40, -40, -40],
       [-40, -40, -40]])
>>> dm
array([[  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [ 11.,  12.,  13.],
       [ 16.,  17.,  18.]])
```

From those you could construct the outputs you are after.

If you run into performance problems, your convolution kernels are separable, i.e. the 2D convolution can be split into 2 1D convolutions along orthogonal axes, which should run faster than the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

So, in fact what you're doing by multiplying and summing across a moving window is what's known as convolution.  Numpy/Scipy has this function in the `ndimage` module.  So, you can get an array of `dx` and `dy` instead of just for one window at a time.  Then, you can get the `mag`, `ang`, and `avg` layers with the numpy functions which apply to the entire `dx` and `dy` arrays all at once.  So, calculate each of those layers separately, then return the `dstack` of the three things, if you want it all in one array:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

gx = np.array([[1, 0, -1], [2, 0, -2], [1, 0, -1]])
gy = np.array([[1, 2, 1], [0, 0, 0], [-1, -2, -1]])

def create_vector(image):
    """Creates a gradient vector for each pixel in the image

    Returns: vec_data: [mag, angle, avg_value]"""

    #Apply sobel operator using convolution
    dx = ndimage.convolve(gx, image)
    dy = ndimage.convolve(gy, image)

    vec_data_mag = np.abs(dx) + np.abs(dy)
    vec_data_ang = np.abs(np.arctan2(dy, dx))    # are you sure you want abs here?
    vec_data_avg = ndimage.convolve(np.ones(3,3), image)

    return np.dstack([vec_data_mag, vec_data_angl, vec_data_avg])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I get this error when i run this: ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Comment: Hm, is that from `ndimage.convolve`?  I just saw your other comment, and I'm not sure if you'll be able to use this solution, since the standard `np.convolve` only works on 1d arrays, not 2d, so this answer uses the `scipy.ndimage`'s `convolve`.

Comment: You could use my solution, if you use [the `fft_convolve2d` from here](https://gist.github.com/thearn/5424195)